# Another way to use a variable readed and passed as argument inside a function

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, optimization, while-loop

The script works but is there any way to get the same result without using "tmp" varaible ?

Thanks

```
function ask_version () {
while true ; do
 echo -e "Give the version of" $1
local tmp=$2
read -r tmp

  if [[ ! $tmp =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] ; then
     echo -e "Please respect number format"
  elif [[ $tmp -ne $t ]] ; then
   echo -e "It is not the true number"
  else
    return 0
  fi
done
}

ask_version "APP1" "APP1VERSION"
ask_version "APP2" "APP2VERSION"
```

Comment: what's wrong with using a variable?

Comment: Can you not just use $2 and avoid setting tmp all together?

Comment: @Raman I have tried using $2 and it did not work

Comment: Can you give an example of how you call this function with 2 parameters?

Comment: Are you sure it's working? Because you compare $tmp to $t, and $t is not set. Did you mean to say `local t=$2`? But then you're passing a non-numeric string as $2, so the test will never succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional version of what I think you're after:

```
function ask_version () {
while true ; do
 echo -e "Give the version of $1"
 read -r

  if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] ; then
     echo -e "Please respect number format"
  elif [[ $REPLY -ne $2 ]] ; then
   echo -e "It is not the true number"
  else
    return 0
  fi
done
}

ask_version "APP1" 5
ask_version "APP2" 6
```

It does not use a `tmp` variable; instead, it relies on `read`'s default variable `REPLY`, and then compares that to the function's second parameter `$2`, which I pass in as actual numbers instead of static strings. Perhaps you meant to use variables instead?

```
ask_version "APP1" "$APP1VERSION"
ask_version "APP2" "$APP2VERSION"
```

Comment: Yes, I wanna use these variables later. I found a solution and I replace "-r" by $2 and $REPLY by $[$2] and it worked !!

Comment: if you want to save the user's input into a variable, have the function echo back the $REPLY, and call the function as: `APP1VERSION=$(ask_version APP1)`

Comment: Ok, it is not what I am needing to do. I will answer once again to push my code

Answer (score 0):

So, to avoid conflict, the variable must be either $2 or $REPLY.
Now my code worked when I have used $REPLY but it is tested inside the function (that is inputed by user). But I wanna call the function like this: ask_version "APP1" "APP1VERSION" replacing $REPLY by $APP1VERSION

```
p="5.5.5"

function ask_version () {
while true ; do
echo -e "Give the version of $1"
read -r
  if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$ ]] ; then
    echo -e "Please respect the version format"
  elif [ ! $REPLY == "$p" ] ; then
   echo -e "The version is not the same tagged in GIT"
  else
   return 0
  fi
done
}
```